# How do I iterate through an array of objects inside an array of objects with ngFor? (angular 8 +)

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have searched and found some information here: [Iterate array inside object Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329863/iterate-array-inside-object-angular-6) but I cannot get it to work properly.

I have an API call and it returns an array of objects (DocumentHead):

[image]

Each of these has an object array called documents:

[image]

Each DocumentHead will always have an entry for documents so code below works (sort of)

```
<li *ngFor="let docHead of DocumentHead;">
  {{docHead.documents[0].id}}
</li>
```

(Code {{docHead.documents.id}} says it is undefined)

DocumentHead.documents[0].id will return at least 1 entry id for each of the 5 entries.
What I want is that for each DocumentHead, it will list the id of each entry in documents
I currently have this:

```
<li *ngFor="let docHead of DocumentHead;">
  <div *ngFor="let docs of docHead.documents[i]; let i = index; ">
    <h3> {{docs.category.name}} </h3>
  </div>
</li>
```

but getting error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

(It won’t allow “let docs of docHead.documents, gives error:
Type DocumentsModel is not assignable to type (DocumentsModel & NgIterable) | undefined | null
)

Tried code from [Loop through array of JSON object with *ngFor (Angular 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402215/loop-through-array-of-json-object-with-ngfor-angular-4)

```
<div *ngFor="let recipient of docHead.documents | keyvalue">
  {{recipient.key}} --> {{recipient.value}}
</div>
```

And getting this output

[image]

This is close to what I want.
(In html component getting error:
Argument type DocumentsModel is not assignable to parameter type {[p: string]: number | string | boolean …>)

How can I iterate over docHead.documents so that my list shows the id of all documents?

ETA Model and call

DocumentHeadModel:

```
export class DocumentHeadModel {
 id: string;
 documents: DocumentsModel;
}


export class DocumentsModel {
 id: string;
}
```

call:

```
getDocuments(id: any): Observable<DocumentHeadModel[]> {
   return this.http.get<DocumentHeadModel[]>(this.myURL?id=` + id);
 }
```

Comment: `let docs of docHead.documents[i];` should be `let docs of docHead.documents` I think.  You want to iterate through all the documents for each DocumentHead, not just one, right?

Comment: It won’t allow “let docs of docHead.documents, gives error: Type DocumentsModel is not assignable to type (DocumentsModel & NgIterable) | undefined | null

Comment: Do you have a typedef for your data?  Can you include it?  It looks to me like documents is an array, if you're defining it differently that could cause an error.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I have added my model and my api call

Comment: So the field on `DocumentHeadModel` is called `documents`, but it's an object, not an array, and it represents one document? You need a `DocumentHeadModel` for each `DocumentModel` and there is only one document id per head?

Comment: Should `DocumentsModel.id` be `string[]`?

Comment: It would seem so. I have access to get and post calls, I don't control the information returned.  Each DocumentHeadModel returns one or more documents. Should I change it to be an array in the model?

Comment: Yes, if you're expecting more than one `DocumentModel` per head, then change `DocumentHeadModel.documents` to `DocumentModel[]`. If instead you're expecting one `DocumentModel` with many identifiers per head, then change `DocumentModel.id` to `string[]`.

Comment: @DM I changed it and it works. Thank you. feel a bit stupid now. Will accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```js
const documentHeads = [
    { 
        id: 1, 
        documents: [
            { id: 101, category: { name: 'Astrophysics' }}
        ] 
    },
    { 
        id: 2, 
        documents: [
            { id: 201, category: { name: 'Literature' }},
            { id: 202, category: { name: 'Mathematics' }} 
        ]
    }
];
```

And you want:

```
-- 1
    -- 101
-- 2
    -- 201
    -- 202
```

You would use:

```html
<ol>
    <li *ngFor="let head of documentHeads">
        <p>{{ head.id }}</p>
        <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let doc of head.documents">{{ doc.id }}</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

If you want:

```
-- 101
-- 201
-- 202
```

You would use:

```html
<ol>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let head of documentHead">
        <li *ngFor="let doc of head.documents">{{doc.id}}</li>
    </ng-container>
</ol>
```

Note that you want to use [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) in the second case because you don't want to create an HTML element between the `ol` and `li` elements.

Comment: It won’t allow “let docs of docHead.documents, gives error: Type DocumentsModel is not assignable to type (DocumentsModel & NgIterable) | undefined | null

Comment: `docHead.documents` is not a simple object array? Your question says "Each of these has an object array called documents". Could you please clarify the structure of your API response object and its children?